# QT: How to trigger "bold" upon mousehover of QMenuBar's items

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, qt6

I am using Qt6 to create a cross-platform GUI application. I am playing around with the automatically generated QMenuBar object in Designer Mode. I want to change the QMenuBar items (File, Edit, Help.. ) to bold and red.

I am using the following code in the StyleSheet editor of the MainWindow object:

```
QMenuBar::item:selected {

    font:bold;
    color:red;

}
```

The code works fine for changing the color of the text but it does not set the font to "bold" as I would like. Also, trying to change the font size does not work.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: have you tried using `font-style` instead of `font`? Seems that `font` requires more than just the style. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties for more information.

Comment: I have just tested it. Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: So i tried to change the font size and this did not work. Maybe the menu items have certain restrictions on what you are able to change.

Comment: You are correct: changing the font size does not work either. I am not sure whether it is because by changing the font size/boldness the menuBar will have to resize itself. Changing the color, on the other hand, brings no change in dimensions.

Comment: Side note about customizing menus on cross-platform applications: on some platforms (macOS, Ubuntu, ...) these customizations (such as bold font) will not work if you use native menus (which is by default). So read about attribute `Qt::AA_DontUseNativeMenuBar` which will force using Qt menus instead of native menus. But with this attribute you will lose native look and feel of the menu bar, which many users perceive as bad thing. Therefore I would not recommend any customizing of menus at all...

Comment: Thank you for the side note! So what happens exactly if I create a menu bar and just add menu items to it without any customization? Will the OS enforce a certain look and behaviour to it?

Comment: Also, if it is not advisable to customize the menu bar in order to keep the native look and feel of the OS.. then the menu bar might contrast the look and feel of my application. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 0):

`QMenubar` does not have a `font`, you need to give the `font` separately to `QAction`.  I think this will solve the problem

```
 QMenu *fileMenu ;
 QAction *newAct = new QAction(tr("&New"), this);

 QFont f = newAct->font();
 f.setBold(true);
 newAct->setFont(f);


 fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
 fileMenu->addAction(newAct);
```

[image]

but if you want an active `QAction` then you need to

```
setStyleSheet("QMenu::item:selected {font: bold;}");
```

Comment: I was actually using QMenuBar::item in order to change the font of the items of the menu bar upon mousehover. The code you have shown outputs a bold QAction object. In other words you obtain a bold submenu item.

Comment: did you try  setStyleSheet("QMenu::item:selected {font: bold;}");

Comment: Yes, it does not work unforunately.